# Java Heroku Deployment is failing

Tags: java, maven, heroku, deployment, spark-java

**I keep getting this error when trying to deploy a Java server to Heroku.**

[image]

```
2017-11-18T18:22:34.252354+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web 
processes running" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=javachatapp-dataserver.herokuapp.com request_id=e899dbbc-1687-470d-a14f-2fffd0cdba12 fwd="24.125.73.190" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https

2017-11-18T18:22:34.195269+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/" host=javachatapp-dataserver.herokuapp.com request_id=f3363e55-f850-4235-90e2-6cb6468dc7e5 fwd="24.125.73.190" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

I think it has an incorrect path in the Profile, because when Heroku is building, I see this Error:

```
2017-11-18T01:04:45.763178+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `java -jar ./target/chatappdataserver-1.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar`
2017-11-18T01:04:47.619837+00:00 app[web.1]: Setting JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS defaults based on dyno size. Custom settings will override them.
2017-11-18T01:04:47.620602+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: Unable to access jarfile ./target/chatappdataserver-1.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar
```

But this is literally what my Procfile has in it:

```
web: java -jar ./target/chatappdataserver-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar
```

When I log into bash on heroku, and start the server manually with the above command it works, but I can't seem to get heroku to start the server with `heroku open`. It crashes on every release. Has anyone seen this before?

**Procfile in Heroku**
[image]

---

**pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.wisen.chatappdataserver</groupId>
    <artifactId>chatappdataserver</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>


    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sparkjava</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <!-- This tells Maven to include all dependencies -->
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>Main</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.heroku.sdk</groupId>
                <artifactId>heroku-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.4.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <jdkVersion>1.8</jdkVersion>
                    <appName>javachatapp-dataserver</appName>
                    <processTypes>
                        <!-- Tell Heroku how to launch your application -->
                        <web>java -jar ./target/chatappdataserver-1.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar</web>
                    </processTypes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>



</project>
```

Answer (score 2):

I see two thing that are interesting.

Your procfile refers to

`web: java -jar ./target/chatappdataserver-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar`

Which is reasonable since your pom defines the version as `1.0-SNAPSHOT` but Heroku tries to find the jar file `java -jar ./target/chatappdataserver-1.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar` according to the log you shared.

That is strange and something you need to understand. Or change your version in your pom to `1.0`

Version don't have to be appended with `SNAPSHOT`.

The other thing that I think is strange is that you don't specify the port you will be using. Heroku dynamically assigns a port and they will then route calls from your host `javachatapp-dataserver.herokuapp.com` on port 80 to this dynamically assigned port.

In my procfile, I have defined a port like this

`-Dport=$PORT`

My complete procfile looks like this

`web:    java $JAVA_OPTS -Dport=$PORT -jar ./build/libs/tage-1.0-SNAPSHOT-all.jar`

I'm building using Gradle so the path to the jar file is different. But thats the only big difference between using Maven and Gradle in this context.

Comment: It was because the web process in the pom.xml file was referring to: `java -jar ./target/chatappdataserver-1.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar`. I changed it to: `web: java -jar ./target/chatappdataserver-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar`, and everything worked.

Answer (score 0):

Try running

```
$ heroku ps:scale web=1
```

This will ensure a web dyno is running. Something in a previous deploy may have caused it to scale down.

Comment: When I run that command it says couldn't find that process type. I am actually on the free tier in heroku, and already have a repo deployed; might that be the reason to why it isn't working?

Comment: Are you deploying with Git? Is your Procfile checked in?

Comment: I deployed using maven: `mvn heroku: deploy`, `heroku open`. However, the first time I deployed, it was via git: `git push heroku master`, `heroku open`. I deleted that entire repo from Heroku, and re-deployed using maven.

Comment: What config is in your pom.xml?

Comment: I basically followed this  [java-apart tutorial](https://sparktutorials.github.io/2015/08/24/spark-heroku.html)

Comment: I will upload my pom.xml file

Comment: That article is very old. Update your heroku-maven-plugin to version 2.0.1

Comment: Ok, will do.  I think the problem might also be that the web process type is:     `java -jar ./target/chatappdataserver-1.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar` in the pom.xml

Comment: Yes, it was the `web process`, thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in:

```
<!-- Tell Heroku how to launch your application -->
<web>java -jar ./target/chatappdataserver-1.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar</web>
```

You must write the name of your artifactId-version-descriptorRef.jar in your case: chatappdataserver-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar